# Как вывести колонку из базы данных?

Tags: python, sqlite

Пишу бота для телеграмма, использую базу данных SQLite

В базе данных есть 2 колонки 'id' и 'amount'

- id - id пользователя телеграмм
- amount - баланс пользователя

Как сделать вывод amount нужного пользователя? Человек пишет "Баланс", бот должен отправить amount этого пользователя, как реализовать?

Comment: Необходимо выполнить запрос
`"SELECT amount FROM Tablename WHERE id = ?"`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT amount
FROM amounts
WHERE id = id_user;
```